# Jenkins workflow (pipeline) - build job only when there are SCM changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm creating quite complicated workflow using the workflow-plugin (Renamed to Pipeline Plugin). For simplicity let's assume I need to build a job, but this job is quite expensive and it doesn't need to be build every time. Only when there are some SCM changes.

So let's call this job ***expensiveJob*** and it's Source Code Management there is ***SCMRepositoryA***.

So I basically want to say

```
build job: 'expensiveJob'
```

And I want to poll for SCM changes and build the job based on that information.

Is there a way how to do this?

My current solution is that I have to checkout in pipeline script the ***SCMRepositoryA*** and then check the *currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets* seems to me like quite a lot of unnecessary work and possibly have to align with whatever Source Code Management changes in my jobs..

Comment: Is `Periodic check SCM`, under `Build trigger`, within Job configuration what you are looking for?

Comment: No, this job can influence results of my other jobs. So it has to be orchestrated from the workflow(pipeline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not currently an equivalent of the `build` step that would merely initiate polling, as opposed to unconditionally scheduling a build.

Writing such a step, or making it an option of the `build` step, would not be particularly difficult I think. In the meantime, for a non-sandboxed script, you could do the same with direct Jenkins API calls: if the downstream project had a configured SCM trigger (need only poll `@daily`, or have no schedule at all), then

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('downstream').SCMTrigger.run()
```

would probably suffice to schedule polling immediately (untested). Alternately, if you wanted to run the polling directly, or did not want to assume even a blank `SCMTrigger, then

```
if (Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('downstream').poll(TaskListener.NULL).hasChanges()) {
    build 'downstream'
}
```

(again untested) could work. The API calls would probably need to be wrapped in a `@NonCPS` method, though, since intermediate results are not `Serializable`:

```
if (poll('downstream')) {
    build 'downstream'
}
@NonCPS boolean poll(String job) {
    Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job).poll(TaskListener.NULL).hasChanges()
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Jesse!

Answer (score 1):

Using the accepted answer, this is how I have setup my declarative pipeline to skip some expensive stages that depend on a job being up to date or not

```
stages {
    stage('Need to build?') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.changesPending = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('expensive').poll(hudson.model.TaskListener.NULL).hasChanges()
                echo "env.changesPending=" +env.changesPending
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Pre-requisites') {
        when {
            expression { env.changesPending == true }
        }
        steps {
            build 'expensive'
        }
    }
    ...
```

This required several script authorizations in http://your-jenkins/scriptApproval/ before it worked